# how to filter letter and number in one column with pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I want to filter number less than 3 **including ".":**

```
import pandas as pd
data = {"numbers":[1,2,".", 3,4, "."]}
data
{'numbers': [1, 2, '.', 3, 4, '.']}
df=pd.DataFrame(data)
df
numbers
0       1
1       2
2       .
3       3
4       4
5       .
```

The result I want should like this:

```
numbers
0       1
1       2
2       .
5       .
```

Can someone help me?
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
In [198]: df[pd.to_numeric(df.numbers, errors='coerce').lt(3) | df.numbers.eq('.')]
Out[198]:
  numbers
0       1
1       2
2       .
5       .
```

Comment: Sorry , I edit it now. And I tried like this, but failed

    `
    df.apply(lambda x: "True" if (x == "." or x <= 0.05) else "False")
   `

The markdown language here is a little different from that  I used maybe.

Comment: Thank you Zero, if I want to mark the eligible ones as “True” and the others as "False"，can you corret my answer above？

Answer (score 0):

Create a mask `m` for where numbers equals `.`

```
m = df.numbers == '.'
```

Convert rows that don't match `.` to `int` & check whether they are below the threshold. Combine the two filters to get the desired output.

```
df[m | (df.numbers[~m].astype(int) < 3)]
#outputs:
  numbers
0       1
1       2
2       .
5       .
```

Answer (score 0):

one way to solve this,

```
print df[(df['numbers']<3)|(df['numbers']=='.')]
```